# SignalR client not connecting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I have a hub as follows:

```
public class MessagingHub : Hub
{
    private static readonly IHubContext HubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MessagingHub>();
    public static void ServerSendClaimNotice(Claim claim)
    {
        HubContext.Clients.All.showClaimNotice(claim);
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

So far it is exclusively for sending messages from MVC controllers to views.

I also have the following method in my `Startup` class:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ConfigureAuth(app);
    app.MapSignalR();
}
```

Then I have the following view script:

```
var msgHub;
$(function() {

    var msgHub = $.connection.messagingHub;
    msgHub.client.showClaimNotice = function(claim) {
        debugger;
        displayClaimNotice(claim);
    };
    $.connection.hub.start()
        .done(function() {
            console.log('Now connected');
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log('Could not connect');
        });
});
```

On calling `$.connection.hub.start`, I would expect the `OnConnected` method to be invoked, and it is not. When `ServerSendClaimNotice` is invoked, nothing at all happens in the client code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the displayClaimNotice?

Comment: Have you setup SignalR in your Startup (`Startup.cs`) via `app.MapSignalR()`?

Comment: @SirwanAfifi, that's a function that opens a modal dialogue to display a message that a claim has been received.

Comment: @BrendanGreen Yes. Please see my edits, where I have now included the `Startup` class method that calls `app.MapSignalR()`.

Comment: Have you included the signalR javascript client in the layout or view `<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the static method is valid for signalr clients to call?

This is an assumption (looking for verification in the docs): The static method as is is to be used from outside the hub context (e.g. your backend process, host process etc.). I guess the hub is not available as there's no *callable* method (That would explain, that the `OnConnected` is not invoked).

Can you try to add a non-static method and see that the client can then connect successfully?

**EDIT**

Maybe I should rephrase: Could be that the Hub Proxy is not available as there's no non-static method to be called from within the caller's context. Could you add a non-static method and check if the connection to the hub is then happening?

Comment: The static method isn't supposed to be called by the client, but by a controller action on the server, in the same assembly as the hub.

Comment: I assumed that. I think I've read if there's not "valid" callable method on the hub, then no client can actually connect to the hub.

Comment: Strange: I got home from work and tried again, and everything works, without change. But your answer has been helpful and though provoking.

Comment: So you're getting into OnConnected?

Comment: Yep, and the client gets called when the server calls the static method.

Comment: Provoking? Well it's been a guess more or less with no profound prove, so yes, it's been not much of a useful contribution.

Comment: One more workaround: if kestral causes the error - change to iis express and rerun locally - error goes away. Of course - not cool - but that helped in my case

Answer (score -1):

I assume an issue in js code

> ```
> $.connection.hub.start()
>     .done(function() {
>         console.log('Now connected');
>  })
>     .fail(function() {
>         console.log('Could not connect');
>     });
> ```

it should look like:

```
$.connection.hub.start()
    .done(function() {
        console.log('Now connected');
    });
$.connection.hub.start()
    .fail(function() {
        console.log('Could not connect');
    });
```